# react-toastify shows before i click

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query, react-toastify

I've made`notify` function which takes parameter

```
const notify = (error) => {
    toast.error(error)
}
```

and dom as

```
<button onClick={notify(error)}>Submit</button>
```

where `error` is my useState hook , which is set if something is fetched from redux rtk. I've put setError which listen through useEffect hook as following

```
const [loginUser, {data, isError, emessage}] = useLoginUserMutation();
const [error, setError] = useState('')
useEffect(() => {
   if(isError){
      setError(emessage.data.errors)
   }
},[isError, data, emessage])
```

I tried to use something like this way

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(isError){
   toast(emessage.data.errors)
}
})
```

which fortunately works only in  second times ,  weirdly shows blank popups in first error message in two popup at same time then stops.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it in as a callback, not directly execute it on render:

```js
<button onClick={() => notify(error)}>Submit</button>
```